# Clojure finding rectangle area

Tags: clojure

```
(defn -main []
  (println "\nTo compute the area of a rectangle,")
  (print   " enter its width: ") (flush)
  (let [ Width (read) ]
    (assert (>= Width 0) "-main: Width must be positive"))
  (print " enter its height: ") (flush)
  (let [ Height (read) ]
    (assert (>= Height 0) "-main: Height must be positive")
    (printf "\nThe area is %f %f\n\n" (rectangleArea Width Height  ))
```

I'm new to Clojure and
there is an unable to resolve symbol error whenever I'm trying to compile the printf function

Comment: Please edit your question and add the whole code and the error that you are getting so people can help you better. It seems to be a problem could be that `Width` is bound only up to the first assertion, but on the last line, `Width` is not defined because you closed the `let` too early. Also, the format string in the last line contains two `%f` but only one value is provided, so it might throw a `MissingFormatArgumentException`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to this so I'm just getting used to it. Will do better next time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you provided an incomplete example, after a few changes it seems that your problem is you're using `%f` to format an integer (java.lang.Long):

```
(defn -main []
  (println "\nTo compute the area of a rectangle,")
  (print   " enter its width: ") (flush)
  (let [ Width (read) ]
    (assert (>= Width 0) "-main: Width must be positive"))
  (print " enter its height: ") (flush)
  (let [ Height (read) ]
    (assert (>= Height 0) "-main: Height must be positive")
    (printf "\nThe area is %f %f\n\n" (+ 10 20  ))))

(-main)
;;=> 
1. Unhandled java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException
   f != java.lang.Long
```

And of course your let blocks are incorrect, so it should be more like this:

```
(defn- read-size [label]
  (print  " enter its " label ":")
  (flush)
  (let [num (read)]
    (assert (>= num 0) (str  label " must be positive"))
    num))

(defn -main []
  (println "\nTo compute the area of a rectangle,")
  (flush)
  (let [width (read-size "width")
        height (read-size "height")]
    (printf "\nThe area is %d \n\n" (* width height))))
```

Comment: (defn rectangleArea [width height] (* width height) I'm using this as my main function to compute the area of rectangle and the following code is the execution but can't seem let it work

Comment: @hkira1 is this a different issue then? What does it mean "can't seem let it work"? Could you be more specific? (btw. you're missing the final right brace in the code you shared in your comment - should be `(defn rectangle-area [width height] (* width height))`

Answer (score 1):

Your test is a main program, C style. Don't do this. Write your program as named functions and use the REPL to exercise them. For starters, this separates the compile errors from the execution errors.

I've called your function `area`. First blood drawn by the compiler is ...

```
Syntax error compiling at (amuse.clj:24:39).
Unable to resolve symbol: rectangleArea in this context
```

Quite right. You have not either by `let` or `def` given a meaning to `rectangleArea`. Removing it and trying again gives a similar error:

```
Syntax error compiling at (amuse.clj:24:39).
Unable to resolve symbol: Width in this context
```

The trouble is that, as [Juraj Martinka](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60071707/1562315) noted, you are outside the `let` binding  for `Width` when you refer to it. Removing `Width` too, we get a clean compile. Let's try calling the function:

```
=> (area)

To compute the area of a rectangle,
 enter its width: 8
 enter its height: 9
Execution error (ClassCastException) at amuse/area (amuse.clj:24).
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

What's happening? The call to `printf` evaluates the expression `(Height)`, which in this instance attempts to call the number `8.0` as a function.

Try, too, to avoid baking input/output interactions into your functions. Arguments and results are better. You can use [keyword arguments](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring#_keyword_arguments) and return maps to convey meaning. Your function might be written ...

```
(defn area [& {:keys [height width]}]
  {:area (+ height width)})
```

This looks bizarre, but is easy to use:

```
=> (area :height 8 :width 9)
{:area 17}
```

Is this correct? I don't think so. We ought to multiply, not add:

```
(defn area [& {:keys [height width]}]
  {:area (* height width)})
amuse=> (area :height 8 :width 9)
{:area 72}
```

So our function is essentially a synonym for `*`.

If I were you, I'd let the REPL take the strain of validation for now. When you have serious work to do, you'll find [Clojure spec](https://clojure.org/guides/spec) very handy indeed.

All the best.